# countdown timer as per video length

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, countdowntimer

Trying to create horizontal progressbar as per video length using countdown timer.

I have a  videoview and horizontal progress bar and what i'm trying to do is run progress bar as per videos length using countdown timer

```
long totalDuration = videoDataView.getDuration();
long currentDuration = videoDataView.getCurrentPosition();

int progress = (int) (ConstantMethods.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(totalDuration,100) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        single_progress.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
};

timer.start();
```

I expect it to run as per videos length but when i run the app progress bar doesnt start.

Comment: @deHaar getProgressPercentage returns int so there is no need to type cast.

Comment: but thank you anyways.

Comment: I just adjusted the intendation and haven't added any code... That cast was there before my edit. But no problem, you can just remove it...

Comment: no issues thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

```
              <ProgressBar 
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_header_relativelayout"
                />


        ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
        int i=0;

            mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
               mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
                        i++;
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int)i*100/(5000/1000));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                    //Do what you want 
                        i++;
                        mProgressBar.setProgress(100);
                    }
                };
                mCountDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: i have already tried this and it will not run as per videos length please read question carefully.